# Finding duplicate entries and updating a column - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with `userID, sectionId, usersectionID, valid` columns. This valid column is used to identify the duplicate entries. But some of the duplicate entries have mixed in valid column.

```
select userID, sectionId, count(*) as cnt from table where valid = 1 group by 1,2 having cnt >1 ;
```

This would show me the list of userID and sectionID combinations duplicate entries. If a userid and sectionID combination has more than 1 entry, then it means there is a duplicate entry.

For example this may be the output,

```
userId      SectionID        Cnt
1               4             3
```

Now when we see this further,

```
Select userId, sectionId, usersectionID, valid from table where userID = 1 and sectionID = 4;

userID      sectionID   usersectionID   valid
1              4            3             1
1              4            5             1
1              4            10            1
```

I want to update the valid column with 0 for all the entries except minimum of usersectionID. The output after this query should be,

```
userID      sectionID   usersectionID   valid
1              4            3             1
1              4            5             0
1              4            10            0
```

I want to do this for the complete table in a single query. I have tried this for a long time with much success. Can anybody help me in solving this? or may be even give some idea in getting this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an UPDATE with a self-JOIN to find the duplicates that should be marked invalid.

```
UPDATE table AS t1
JOIN (SELECT userID, sectionID, MIN(usersectionID) AS minusersectionID
      FROM table
      WHERE valid = 1
      GROUP BY userID, sectionID) AS t2 
ON t1.userID = t2.userID AND t1.sectionID = t2.sectionID AND t1.usersectionID != t2.minusersectionID
SET t1.valid = 0
WHERE t1.VALID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following approach.

**Update based on Minimum**

```
Update TableName
JOIN (
    SELECT userID, sectionID, MIN(userSectionID) AS minuserSectionID
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY userID, sectionID
) AS T
Set Valid = 1
WHERE 
TableName.userID = T.userID
AND TableName.sectionID = T.sectionID
AND TableName.userSectionID = T.minuserSectionID;
```

OR USE 
**Update based on Ranked 1st value**

```
SET @rank=0;
Update TableName
JOIN (
    SELECT userID, sectionID, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rownumber
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY userID, sectionID
) AS T
Set Valid = 1
WHERE 
TableName.userID = T.userID
AND TableName.sectionID = T.sectionID
AND T.rownumber = 1;
```